# TCPDF: How make a pdf in Landscape, splitted in 2 parts and print a table in first row and go next 2nd?

Tags: php, tcpdf

Sorry for title not very clear.

I'm using TCPDF.

I need print a table in a PDF, landscape. If data are more than available space of first row, goes to second row.

An image of my expected result (dimensions are not real, but it gives the idea):

[image]

Data are from an array, in PHP (**pseudocode**)

```
array(
[0]=> 'name'=>'Alessandro','age'=>'30')
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: hi , Are You check this link http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_028.pdf

Answer (score 0):

you have to check how many columns fits in to one page; if the result is not more than one page you start a a4 page, if the result is more than to fit in a4 page, that you start creating a A3 landscape page.